# How are r.horizon results aligned?

Tags: grass-gis

I used r.horizon to calculate horizon on a raster every 10° without any offset. I have got 36 files now.

Is the first file from 0° to 10° (then centered on azimuth=5°) or is it centered on 0°, in this case the first file is from 355° to 5° (knowing that GRASS start 0 in the East counterclockwise)?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I completely misunderstand [`r.horizon`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.horizon.html), when creating raster output it calculates the height of the horizon for *each* point (cell) for the given direction. So if you don't set `direction` and your `horizonstep` is 10 degrees you will get the height of the horizon for directions 0°, 10°, 20°, etc. It does not represent the height of the horizon between 355° to 5°, 5° to 15° and so on, but only for the specified azimuth.

If you use `r.horizon` as input for `r.sun` you probably should use the same `horizonstep` for both for it to be useful.

Comment: Note that r.sun does not require r.horizon, it can calculate it by itself (it is just a bit slower then).